# Jquery Check Onclick for element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before adding `$('.dropdown-toggle').click`, I want to make sure there is no callback bound to `dropdown-toggle`. I am wondering how can I check?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function (e) {
        console.log("aaa")
        $(this).parent().parent().children().eq(1).toggle()
    });
```

I checked other post, I tried:

```
if ($('.dropdown-toggle').attr("onClick") != undefined)


$('.dropdown-toggle').click == undefined
```

But, it doesn't work.

Can I get some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work.

```js
hasClickListener = function(el) {
  let listeners = $._data(el[0], "events")

  return (listeners !== undefined && listeners.click !== null) || el.prop("onclick") !== null;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  // false
  console.log(hasClickListener($("#click_here")));

  $("#click_here").click(function() {
    // Do something
  });

  // true
  console.log(hasClickListener($("#click_here")));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="click_here">Click here</div>
```

Comment: If you modify the return line you can cover the `onclick` handlers aren't jquery event handlers: `return (listeners !== undefined && listeners.click !== null) || el.prop("onclick") !== null;`